# System datetime has changed event

Tags: android

Is there any way to handle changes of system date/time on android?
The goal of it is to control behavior of application if user changes datetime on purpose to  make an app running during restrictive time.

Comment: Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android) helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are broadcasts for those events.
ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and ACTION_DATE_CHANGED

ACTION docs at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED

A potential bug and some implementation details available at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2880