# how to create a time change listener

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an application that will create a persistent notification but I need to update this notification each day so is there a way to create a time listener or how to do it otherwise but I need this update to be performed even if the activity is not started, so even if the user did not open the application, I saw this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android) but it's just for an app that is still in its started state once it's in its pause state... it won't work anymore... any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an AlarmManager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Set up the alarm to trigger at the time you want to handle your event.

When you complete your event code, set up a new Alarm before you exit.

Note that alarms do not survive a reboot so you would need to set them up again at device boot (if required)

Comment: thnaks will try that.

Answer (score 2):

The Best way is to use AlarmManager see this link http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

Otherwise you will need to write service to keep track on time.

Good luck