# How to receive time format changed 12 to 24 vice versa from native device settings?

Tags: android

I have a requirement to update the current time in my application as per device **time format(12/24)**. I need any **callback/listeners/receivers** which will let me know that time format has been changed so that i can update time in my application accordingly.

I got the way to get current timeformat using below code snippet

```
String value = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(this.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.TIME_12_24);
```

But looking for any callback which will let me know the same in run time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you tried with default date format checker

Comment: i think you dint get my question .. i asked for any call back or receiver which will let me know if format is changed.

Comment: Do you see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6230951 ??

Comment: @Sreekanth there is no separate filter for time format but timeset filter is working for time format also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(Context context);
>   Use this function to get the time format.
>   Register a Broadcast receiver which listens to **ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED**,**ACTION_TIME_CHANGED**,**ACTION_TIME_TICK**.

Something like this,

```
IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(youReciverHere,intentFilter);
```

Do work on the receiver s onReceive() function.