# Can MDM restrict user to change date time settings

Tags: android, ios, security, mdm

Through MDM policy prevent user to change the date time settings?  Can Device date and time should be controlled from server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDM protocol/Configuration profiles doesn't have such functionality.

Potentially, you can find some private API's which can help you with that. However, it's time consuming (to find such a thing) and you can't release such things to App Store.

Answer (score 1):

MDM does not support such functionality as Ram mentioned. In case you need to know if the user has changed time then following can help.

[Date and time change listener in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android)

Please register the broad cast receiver in static way.