# How can I get System Time before changed it

Tags: android, time, broadcast, receiver

I'm using a Broadcast receiver to know when time is changed.

```
public class TimeChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Your time was changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I would like to know the system time before this receiver. To compare the time before whith the current time.

Comment: explain more when time changed where? the user change?

Comment: Have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android

Comment: When the user change time at System options. I need to know what time was before he changed.