# Getting server time for android app?

Tags: android, mysql, datetime, ntp

My app contains listview that are time limited. In another activity, I have a `PostActivity` that let's user post something to mysql server using volley. User post are time-limited. After posting their content, they can post again after a certain hour or minutes. As I mentioned before that my listview is time-limited, they contain `timeCreated` & `timeExpiry`. Whenever the user logins and tries to post something, I get the value of `timeExpiry` and check if 
`timeExpiry - currentTime` **(timeExpiry, currentTime & timeCreated) are all in** `milliseconds`

```
Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

Long remainingTime = userDate.getTimeExpiry - currentTime;

if (remainingTime > 0 || remainingTime == 0) { 
//User is allowed to post
}
```

**!Wait** User can change their mobile time and post unlimitedly!!

Now for the sake of simplicity, is there anyway to get the time from my `mysql server` or from a `NTP-Server`. I tried alot of classes such as the `SntpClient` class**(link below)** `

> but I get the date before 1970-1-1

https://gist.github.com/prasann/9003350

I used this function but the method `DateUtils.getFormattedDateTime()` was not implemened in any `DateUtils` class.

```
public String getUTCTime(){
    long nowAsPerDeviceTimeZone = 0;
    SntpClient sntpClient = new SntpClient();

    if (sntpClient.requestTime("0.de.pool.ntp.org", 30000)) {
        nowAsPerDeviceTimeZone = sntpClient.getNtpTime();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone timeZoneInDevice = cal.getTimeZone();
        int differentialOfTimeZones = timeZoneInDevice.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());
        nowAsPerDeviceTimeZone -= differentialOfTimeZones;
    }
    return DateUtils.getFormattedDateTime(new Date(nowAsPerDeviceTimeZone));
}
```

> "0.de.pool.ntp.org" NTP-Server time for Germany

Comment: a simple way could be listen to time change event in mobile and act based on this, like setting a flag in preferences that user have manipulated time, and should not post... etc, check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android

Comment: Thanks! For the sake of my protocol, i will use this method.

Comment: Did you try any of these: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20get%20time%20from%20internet