# How to detect time change event in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want my application to push a notification at a particular time set by the user(similar to an alarm clock app). Which broadcast should be detected by my receiver?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android

Comment: will this work for a particular time set in the app....Like for example if i want a notification exactly at 8:30 AM?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an alarm using `AlarmManager`. There is no standard broadcast event that you can listen for. There are tons of examples of how to do this, just search for them.